# Assets out of memory

Tags: assets, php-errors, s3, amazons3, php.ini

memory_limit is 2048M (from 7GB)

but I got error when indexed big amazon s3 folder

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 25415 bytes)

Tried add `$config['assets_memory_limit'] = 1024;` and `$config['memory_limit'] = 1024;`

EE 2.9.2, Assets 2.5

I see they already fixed this problem in version 2.3

- Fixed an issue where Assets could run out of memory when browsing
  large folders.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed:

I found `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` in `/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/sources/s3/source.s3.php` and changed it to `1024M`

Comment: Hopefully P&T's aware of this and it'll get rolled into another update; just ran into the same issue.