# Assets not working with Amazon S3 external source

Tags: assets, amazons3

I have set up an external source for S3 and it's not working. I cannot update the index - the white bar shows up but nothing happens.

I cannot upload - when I try, I get this error dialog box: "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings."

I am using Assets 2.5 and EE v2.9.2 - Build Date: 20141004.

I would appreciate any help on this. thanks!

Comment: I tried increasing the memory limit as explained here but that didn't work either. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30694/assets-out-of-memory